# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, mapbox

Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip'.
The specified initialization script '/tmp/d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle' does not exist.

Im using: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip in my gradle-wrapper.properties.

And my project-level build.gradle is:

```
/*
The build.gradle file (also known as the app-level build.gradle) is a configuration file 
used to define various settings and dependencies for a specific module in your Android project. 
This file is located in the app directory of your project. It includes settings related to dependencies, 
plugins, build types, flavors, and more.
*/
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories{
        google()  // Adding the Google Maven repository for Google dependencies
        mavenCentral()  // Adding the Maven Central repository for Java libraries
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
              authentication {
                  basic(BasicAuthentication)
              }
              credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                  username = project.properties['MAP_BOX_USERNAME'] ?: ""
                  // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                  password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
              }
        }
    }
    /*
        Note: Make sure that the google and gradle version fits together.
    */
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

//Applies to all modules
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
              authentication {
                  basic(BasicAuthentication)
              }
              credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                  username = project.properties['MAP_BOX_USERNAME'] ?: ""
                  // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                  password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
              } 
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried to clean my gradle cache through:
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assemble
./gradlew build
Also flutter build appbundle

Also deleted my .gradle folder (user level) on my Linux pc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem. **You must uninstall the VS Code Java Extension Pack**. This worked for me.

More information at... https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134714